# Validation on TextBox: red border does not always appear on invalid results

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox

I have a textbox that is bound to a property that requires a value, ie:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "required value")]
 public string SomeText
 {
     //get set...
 }
```

And in my XAML, I have the following setup for my textbox:

```
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true
```

As expected, the red border appears when there is no value in the textbox, however when I select a different tab and then go back to the page with the invalid results, the red border no longer appears. It only reappears if I enter a valid result and then erase it.

How can I debug this? How can I find out what event causes the red border to appear?

Comment: Please show your `IDataErrorInfo` validation code as well. I suspect it has something to do with TabItems unloading their children if that tab is not selected (default behavior), and the validation only occurring when a value gets changed, not when it is initially loaded.

Comment: I cannot post all this code, however in the `get` of my `public string this[string columnName`, it does return an appropriate error string if I put a breakpoint here, but the red border does not show.

Comment: Are you sharing the ViewModel between the tab views?  You may need to run a notify on the textbox binding if you switch the context using the same ViewModel.  Just a thought...

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes looks like the viewmodel is shared. I am fairly new to WPF though, how would I perform a notify on the textbox binding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WPF when items on the tab get unloaded from the visual tree the fact that they were marked invalid is lost. Basically, when a validation error happens the UI responds to an event in the validation stack and marks the item invalid. This marking doesn't get re-evaluated when the item comes back into the visual tree unless the binding is also re-evaluated (which it usually isn't if the user clicks on a tab item).

Define a function like this somewhere (I put it in a static ValidationHelper class along with some other things):

```
public static void ReMarkInvalid( DependencyObject obj )
{
    if( Validation.GetHasError( obj ) ) {
        List<ValidationError> errors = new List<ValidationError>( Validation.GetErrors( obj ) );
        foreach( ValidationError error in errors ) {
            Validation.ClearInvalid((BindingExpressionBase)error.BindingInError);
            Validation.MarkInvalid((BindingExpressionBase)error.BindingInError, error);
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( obj ); i++ ) {
        ReMarkInvalid( VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( obj, i ) );
    }
}
```

I think you can call this function in the TabControl's Selected event and it should have the desired effect. E.g.:

```
private void TabControl_Selected(...) 
{
    ReMarkInvalid( tabControl );
}
```

If that doesn't work you may need to do this at a lower Dispatcher priority to make sure the visual tree has finished loading first. Which would look like replacing ReMarkInvalid... with:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action( delegate()
{
    ReMarkInvalid( tabControl );
} ), DispatcherPriority.Render );
```

Comment: thank-you for this! I tried these but unfortunately did not work. I first tried `ReMarkInvalid((TabControl)sender)` inside `TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)` event, but no luck. I then tried replacing the `ReMarkInvalid` in here with the `Dispatcher.BeginINvoke` call. But no luck :s

Comment: although I do see that `Validation.GetHasError` returns true where it should.

Comment: okay - turns out I had to perform a ClearInvalid as well. It worked! Thanks!

Comment: great solution! I learnt so much from so little code. Thanks a bunch +1

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put the contents of your tab inside **AdornerDecorator** tags:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>

        <AdornerDecorator>

            <ContentControl Content="{Binding TabItemViewModel}" />
            <Grid>
                <!-- Other Stuff -->
            </Grid>

        </AdornerDecorator>

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

#### Update:

AdornerDecorator doesn't render borders on controls that are invisible (in unselected tabs). It just preserves borders across tabs once the borders have already been rendered.

However, the code put above by Dana Cartwright works fine. You just have to put a **ClearInvalid** before **MarkInvalid** as pointed out by lost_bits1110:

```
Validation.ClearInvalid((BindingExpressionBase)error.BindingInError);
Validation.MarkInvalid((BindingExpressionBase)error.BindingInError, error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a particularly troublesome situation where [@dana-cartwright's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603498J) is not having an effect.

I've found that I'm able to get the desired behavior if I reset the binding in error completely:

```
private static void ResetBindingsWithError(DependencyObject obj)
{
    if (Validation.GetHasError(obj))
    {
        // Loops over each of the dependency object's bindings that have errors
        foreach (BindingExpression bindingExpression in
                 Validation.GetErrors(obj)
                           .Select(validationError => validationError.BindingInError)
                           .OfType<BindingExpression>()
                           .ToArray())
        {
            // Reset the binding
            Binding binding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
            DependencyProperty targetProperty = bindingExpression.TargetProperty;

            if (bindingExpression.TargetProperty == null)
            {
                // Clearing one binding, may affect others that result in a TargetProperty of null
                continue;
            }

            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(obj, targetProperty);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(obj, targetProperty, binding);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        ResetBindingsWithError(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
    }
}
```

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not TabControl tabControl)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Event should only fire against TabControl");
    }

    // `sender` will always be the TabControl the event was registered against, but
    // `e.OriginalSource` will be the Selector that produced the event. Because this is a
    // bubbling event, we only want to handle the event if the sender is our top-level
    // TabControl.
    if ((tabControl == e.OriginalSource) &&
        (tabControl.SelectedContent is DependencyObject tabControlContent))
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ResetBindingsWithError(tabControlContent));
    }
}
```